# Is CSDA (continuous slowing down approximation) valid only for high energies?

Tags: particle-physics

According to the [NIST](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Star/Text/appendix.html), CSDA (continuous slowing down approximation) is:

> a very close approximation to the average path length traveled by a
>   charged particle as it slows down to rest, calculated in the
>   continuous-slowing-down approximation. In this approximation, the rate
>   of energy loss at every point along the track is assumed to be equal
>   to the total stopping power. Energy-loss fluctuations are neglected.
>   The CSDA range is obtained by integrating the reciprocal of the total
>   stopping power with respect to energy.

I was wondering is this approximation valid only at high energies? I cannot find CSDA range calculation below 10 keV for elecctrons.